# ValueError: Invalid format specifier python

Tags: python

[image]

```
for i in range (0,2):
    f'{{"requests":[{"indexName":"products","params":"query=&hitsPerPage=20&maxValuesPerFacet=1000&page="{i}"&facets=%5B%22family.name%22%2C%22wine_type.name%22%2C%22vina.name%22%2C%22cepa.name%22%2C%22linea.name%22%2C%22procedencia.name%22%2C%22wine_harvest_year%22%2C%22price%22%2C%22score%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%22family.name%3AVinos%22%5D"}]}}'
```

Comment: `f'{{"requests":[{"` there's a single opening brace here.

Comment: For your specific scenario you'd better use a `dict` then `json.dumps`

Comment: curly-brackets  that using as real brackets should be doubled `{{}}`. `f'{{"requests":[{{"indexName":"products","params":"query=&hitsPerPage=20&maxValuesPerFacet=1000&page="{i}"&facets=%5B%22family.name%22%2C%22wine_type.name%22%2C%22vina.name%22%2C%22cepa.name%22%2C%22linea.name%22%2C%22procedencia.name%22%2C%22wine_harvest_year%22%2C%22price%22%2C%22score%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%22family.name%3AVinos%22%5D"}}]}}'` is correct line

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use braces inside format string you have to use it like [this](https://djangocas.dev/blog/python/python-literal-curly-braces-in-f-string/#:%7E:text=Format%20strings%20contain%20%E2%80%9Creplacement%20fields,by%20doubling%3A%20%7B%7B%20and%20%7D%7D.).
Meaning two braces instead of one when you want to insert a brace.
And only one brace when you actually want to format

This is the fixed code:

```
for i in range (0,2):
    f'{{{{"requests":[{{"indexName":"products","params":"query=&hitsPerPage=20&maxValuesPerFacet=1000&page="{i}"&facets=%5B%22family.name%22%2C%22wine_type.name%22%2C%22vina.name%22%2C%22cepa.name%22%2C%22linea.name%22%2C%22procedencia.name%22%2C%22wine_harvest_year%22%2C%22price%22%2C%22score%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%22family.name%3AVinos%22%5D"}}]}}}}'
```

Comment: {'message': 'Expecting map key (near 1:2)', 'status': 400}
it is showing this error

Comment: I guess that this is not a problem with the formatted string anymore.
And for answering this question you'll have to provide more information